# symfony: about an admin module. The size of the table maybe matters?

Tags: symfony1

I'm getting the error below when I try to show the list of an admin 
module (as you can see I send two requests: the first at 18:45 and the 
second at 18:48). The model has 9500 rows in the table.

```
[Mon Jan 30 18:45:07 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal 
error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/javier/ 
eclipse-php/workspace/prueba/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/ 
sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Collection.php on line 
473 
[Mon Jan 30 18:45:07 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal 
error:  Call to a member function shutdown() on a non-object in /home/ 
javier/eclipse-php/workspace/prueba/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/ 
sfContext.class.php on line 594 
[Mon Jan 30 18:45:08 2012] [notice] child pid 1340 exit signal 
Segmentation fault (11) 
[Mon Jan 30 18:48:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not 
exist: /home/javier/eclipse-php/workspace/prueba/web/favicon.ico 
[Mon Jan 30 18:48:34 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal 
error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/javier/ 
eclipse-php/workspace/prueba/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/ 
sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Collection.php on line 
473 
[Mon Jan 30 18:48:35 2012] [notice] child pid 1339 exit signal 
Segmentation fault (11)
```

I don't have any problem with other admin modules based on other 
models that have less rows..So what should I do? In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
I set the memory limit to 4096MB (memory_limit = 4096M).

A clue: this is exactly what is written in line 473 of Collection.php:

```
        /** 
         * for some weird reason in_array cannot be used here (php 
bug ?) 
         * 
         * if used it results in fatal error : [ nesting level too 
deep ] 
         */ 
        foreach ($this->data as $val) { // line 473 
            if ($val === $record) { 
                return false; 
            } 
        }
```

and this is what is written in line 594 in sfContext.class.php:

```
  /** 
   * Execute the shutdown procedure. 
   * 
   * @return void 
   */ 
  public function shutdown() 
  { 
    // shutdown all factories 
    if($this->has('user')) 
    { 
      $this->getUser()->shutdown();  //line 594 
      $this->getStorage()->shutdown(); 
    }
```

Any help?

sf 1.4

Javier

Comment: if you need to process a big amount of data you can change the maximum execution time parameter of your php configuration. But having that problem uses to be a consecuence of a bad design

Comment: I have an admin module with a table containing 750,000 non-trivial records and never ran into that kind of problem.  It works on my Mac and on our production Linux servers fine (all using MySQL).  So there's probably something wrong with either your database design or perhaps a faulty table query you're using.  Did you try specifying and creating a custom table_method for that module's query?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I solved with:

```
filter:
   class: false
```

In the generator.yml.

I had a too much options in select form in my filter